# How do I resolve TF51005 for ReflectedWorkItemId when migrating Azure DevOps data?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server, vsts-sync-migrator, azure-devops-migration-tools

i am trying to migrate a project from one organization project to another Project .
From Source Azure Devops Project to Target DEvops project.

What should be the ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName: ?

i tried changing it to :

```
Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
ReflectedWorkItemId
ProcessName.ReflectedWorkItemId
GlobalWit.ReflectedWorkItemId
```

but its does not helps. Please help me

## error

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId]»
```

===

## my config file

```
"Source": {
"Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/somegDevOps/",
"Project": "ContosoAir",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"PersonalAccessToken": "Intentionally removed"
},
"Target": {
"Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/ITIDEVOPSTEAM/",
"Project": "ContosoAir-Migrated",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"PersonalAccessToken": "Intentionally removed"
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To provide sync as well as migration it is important that the tools knows which items have already been migrated. This is the purpose of the ReflectedWorkItemId field.

This field needs to be added to the Target Project Work Items. If you are using "UpdateSourceReflectedWorkItemID" then it also needs to be added to the Source.

On both system the URL pointing to the migrated item on the other system is stored here. This means there is an easy way for a user to trace work items between the source and target systems (and vice versa).

How the ReflectedWorkItemId field is added depends on whether the system.

- **TFS** / **Azure DevOps Server [XML Process]** - If you are using the classic XML process you will need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019
- **Azure DevOps Service [XML Process]**  - If you use the Microsoft Migration tools to take your entire collection into Azure DevOps Service then you will need to download the XML zip, change the files, and reupload. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops
- **Azure DevOps Service [Inherited Process]** - you can customise and add the ReflectedWorkItemId 
  filed using the GUI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops

Comment: It would be really useful if this was added to the getting started documentation, emphasising that the field needs to be added to each work item type which is going to be migrated.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing  *MrHinsh - Martin Hinshelwood*. Very useful ! Also kindly mark it.